# PDO converts unbound fields to string

Tags: string, pdo, null

i developed a application on my local pc with xampp and everything works fine. Today I have uploaded the code to an synology nas from the customer and every action crashes.

First of all I recognized that in the xampp config php.ini the pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict was not activated. This "activated" some errors on my local PC also.

An other problem are inserts to mariadb by pdo. The database table field is definied as "not null" but on my local PC if I dont specify the field in the insert statement the field is filled with an empty string. On the customers synolgy nas there is an error that the field is "null" which is correct in my opinion but it is hard to find the errors on the local pc without an error message.

I played setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_NATURAL); etc but the is no change... Is there an other point to configure?

Thanks in advice...

I played setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_NATURAL); etc but the is no change...

In the php.ini i did not find any point to this..

Is there an other point to configure?